# unable to push new rails to heroku database error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, sqlite

I am trying to push my app to heroku.

My `Gemfile` looks like below

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

 git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
 repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
 "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
 end

 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
 # Use Puma as the app server
  gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
 # Use SCSS for stylesheets
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
 # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

 # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
  gem 'jquery-rails'
 # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
  gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
 # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
  gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
 # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
  # gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
 # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
  # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

 # Use Capistrano for deployment
 # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

 group :development, :test do
 # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
 end

 group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
 end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data 
 gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

 gem 'pg'
```

I am not able to push when I do `git push heroku master`.

Below is the error which I am getting

> gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> -r remote:        ./siteconf20170706-221-1q194t4.rb extconf.rb remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try
>   'brew install sqlite3', remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or
>   'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev' remote:        and check your shared
>
> shared library is located). remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably
>   lack of necessary remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the
>   mkmf.log file for more details.  You may remote:        need
>   remote:        --with-sqlite3-config remote:
>   which can remote:        be found here: remote:         remote:
>   remote:         remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1 remote:
>   remote:        Gem files will remain installed in remote:
>   remote:         remote:        An error occurred while installing
>   sqlite3 (1.3.13), and
>   Bundler cannot
>   remote:        continue.
>   remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds 
>   remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.

Sorry for the poor format of the question, please suggest what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `gem pg` to heroku because on `posgres` is used on heroku.

or do this:

## Gemfile

```
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'pg', group: :production
```

then

```
bundle install
```

and push `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to heroku

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked, although the images not loading but probably different issue..